# Swift, Combine: Is @Published key word for multiple lines?

Tags: swift, combine

Swift, Combine: Is `@Published` key word for multiple lines? Is it applicable for more than one property?

Example:

```
import Combine

final class Demo: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var value1: Int?
    var value2: Double?
}
```

This is a valid code.
Question: Is @Published applied to value1 and value2? Or only for value1?
Is it one-liner?

Comment: Let's learn swift https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't relate to lines at all.  It's a [property wrapper](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md) that wraps the property right after it.